# What is the alternative solution for @javax.jws.WebMethod(exclude=true)?

Tags: java, annotations, cxf, jax-ws-customization, java2wsdl

In process of up-gradation CXF jars from 2.2.12 to 3.1.6, I am facing issue with "exclude=true" attribute in @javax.jws.WebMethod annotation while building my project. I am getting following exception.

---

> [java] Error: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsConfigurationException: The
>   @javax.jws.WebMethod(exclude=true) cannot be used on a service
>   endpoint interface. Method: deleteFileInternal
>        [java] Use the verbose setting to show the stacktrace of this error
>        [java] JavaToWS Error: org.apache.cxf.tools.common.ToolException: org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsConfigurationException: The
>   @javax.jws.WebMethod(exclude=true) cannot be used on a service
>   endpoint interface.

---

This is due to, CXF 3.1.6 is not supporting "exclude=true" attribute while generation WSDL from java class if class is annotated with @javax.jws.WebService annotation.

Can someone please suggest the alternate solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `@javax.jws.WebMethod(exclude=true)` on the interface, just use it on the implementation

```
public class MyWebServiceImpl implements MyWebService {
    ...
    @WebMethod(exclude = true)
    String methodToExclude(String s) {

    }
}
```

Also you can remove the method from interface